# How do you find the cartridge short names in Openshift?

Tags: openshift

The documentation for using the OpenShift Environment Variables tells you to insert the "cartridge short name" in the variable string for a number of the available Environment Variables.  How do I know what my cartridge's short name is?

For instance, the log path environment variable is supposed to be this:

> OPENSHIFT_{cartridge}_LOG_DIR

The Environment Variable documentation page can be found here: https://www.openshift.com/developers/openshift-environment-variables

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You control what cartridges are installed, so it’s up to you. If you’re making your own cartridge, [specify the short name in `manifest.yml`](https://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#cartridge-metadata). Example from the linked documentation:

```
Name: PHP
Cartridge-Short-Name: PHP
```

Similarly, each cartridge’s `manifest.yml` lists the short name. Here’s the relevant section from the [cron cartridge](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-cron/metadata/manifest.yml):

```
Name: cron
Vendor: Red Hat
Cartridge-Short-Name: CRON
```

Comment: It's not at all up to me.  I have no idea what the short names of my installed cartridges are despite knowing exactly which cartridges I've installed

Comment: You didn’t set up the server? You haven’t given much detail here. Are you able to run the `rhc` commands? `rhc env list` lists the environment variables.

Comment: Dude, what?  Of course I'm able to run the RHC commands.  My app is live and running on the web right now.  Still have no clue what the short name of the cartridges are, because they're not listed anywhere, and that's my question.  Have you ever used OpenShift or did you just try to answer my question by searching Google?

Comment: Dude, you can create an app from their site, too. Since you gave nearly no information, I’ve had to speculate about your setup. Bye now

Comment: This is the absolute worst attempt at an answer I've ever seen.  NEITHER CREATING AN APP FROM RHC TOOLS NOR CREATING AN APP FROM THE WEBSITE REVEALS CARTRIDGE SHORT NAMES!!!!!!

Comment: Okay, sweet.  I was asking about a method for finding the short name for _any_ cartridge, but it looks like you can investigate the manifests of all the available cartridges a [few directories up from the link you gave](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/cartridges).  Thank you.  If you revise your answer to include that link, I'll accept it.